# JavaScript function, if else, isNaN

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I've tried to make a function where you're supposed to enter two numbers in two different boxes and loop it until you put in a valid number!

```
var x = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number!"));
var y = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number!"));

function add(x, y) {

    var z = x + y;
    var i = false;

    do {
        if (isNaN(x)) {
            alert("Invalid entry. Please enter a number!")
        } else if (isNaN(y)) {
            alert("Invalid entry. Please enter a number!")
        } else {

            alert(x + " + " + y + " = ");
            i = true;
        }
        while (i == false);
    }
}

add(x, y);
```

Comment: How about adding the prompts to the loop so one can actually change the values and not just see the alerts ?

Comment: **Wow** that is some misleading indentation. And syntactically-invalid code, in fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with this code:

1. Your while is misplaced.
2. The parameters x and y don't make sense, because the user needs to input them.
3. The prompts asking for the numbers are outside of the loop.

Here is the fixed code:

```
function add() {

    do {
        var x = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number!"));
        var y = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number!"));
        var z = x + y;
        var i = false;

        if (isNaN(x)) {
            alert("Invalid entry. Please enter a number!")
        } else if (isNaN(y)) {
            alert("Invalid entry. Please enter a number!")
        } else {

            alert(x + " + " + y + " = " + z);
            i = true;
        }
    }
    while (i == false);
}

add();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues:

1. It's syntactically invalid. You've ended up with a free-standing `while (i == false);` (which would fine, but it would never end if `i` is ever `false`) and a dangling `}` under your code. You need to move the `while` line beneath the closing `}` of the `do`.
2. If `x` or `y` is `NaN`, your `add` function loops until they change...but no code in that loop ever changes them.

I don't know what you want `add` to do (since just adding numbers doesn't require a function), but if the goal is to keep prompting the user, you have to move the prompts into the loop:

```
function add() {

    var x, y, z;
    var valid = false;

    while (!valid) {
        x = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number!"));
        y = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number!"));
        valid = !isNaN(x) && !isNaN(y);
        if (!valid) {
            alert("Invalid entry. Please enter a number!")
        }
    }
    z = x + y;
    // Do something with z
}

add();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it recursively without using a *do while* loop at all, by asking `x` and `y` values until both are correct. Also, note that I used a radix value of 10 for `parseInt(string, radix);`, the reason being that the documentation describes `radix` as:

> An integer that represents the radix of the above mentioned string.
> Always specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to
> guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce
> different results when a radix is not specified.

See more from the documentation of [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

The code example:

```
function askXY(x, y) {

  var x_ = x,
      y_ = y;

  if(typeof x_ === "undefined") {
     x_ = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number for x!"), 10);
  }

  if(typeof y_ === "undefined") {
     y_ = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number for y!"), 10);
  }

  if(isNaN(x_) || isNaN(y_)) {
     alert("Invalid entry. Please enter a number!");

     // The magic is here, we keep the x or y if either one of those are correct
     // and if not, we give undefined so that value will be asked again from the user
     return askXY(
         !isNaN(x_) ? x_ : undefined,
         !isNaN(y_) ? y_ : undefined
     );
  }

  // success!
  alert(x_ + " + " + y_ + " = " + (x_ + y_));

}

askXY();
```

**See my [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vCNSL/)**.

Comment: Why in heaven's name would you want to use recursion for this?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Because it is possible and imo it looks clean, this is partly just a matter of taste. :) Can you describe why recursion would not be good for this? Servers the purpose.

Comment: Recursion for a simple loop is using the wrong tool for the job, in this case making the code *markedly* more complicated than necessary. You *can* drive a nail with a socket wrench, but best practice is to use a hammer (or a nailgun :-) ).

Comment: I respect your reply but I think your argument is opinion based, which is fine. I wanted to provide an _alternative_ which works and looks clean for my taste. Programming is full of alternative solutions, nothing new here, aight? :)

Comment: Agreed, many things are matters of opinion or taste. But I think using recursion for a simple loop goes beyond mere opinion into objective issues of complication, debugging, stack consumption. In any case, as you say, an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The isNaN() is a JavaScript function. It returns true if the given value is [not a number](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/NaN#Noun) (NaN).

```
var a = isNaN('127') ;       // Returns false
var a = isNaN('1273 ') ;     // Returns false
var b = isNaN(-1.23) ;       // Returns false
var c = isNaN(5-2);          // Returns false
var d = isNaN(0) ;           // Returns false
var e = isNaN("Hell  o") ;   // Returns true
var f = isNaN("2005/12/12"); // Returns true
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = parseInt(prompt("Please enter the first number!"));
    var y = parseInt(prompt("Please enter the second number!"));

    function add(x, y) {

        var z = x + y;
        var i = false;

        do {
            if (isNaN(x)) {
                alert("Invalid entry for first number. Please enter a number!");
                x = parseInt(prompt("Please enter first number again!"));
            } else if (isNaN(y)) {
                alert("Invalid entry for second one. Please enter a number!");
                y = parseInt(prompt("Please enter Second number again!"));
            } else {
                   z = x + y;
                alert(x + " + " + y + " = " + z);
                i = true;
            }
        }while (i == false);

    }

    add(x, y);
});
```

---

This is a compiled demo version. Checkout the Fiddle:

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MjXjd/1/)